# “which in Ruby”: checking if program exists in $PATH from Ruby

Tags: ruby, unix, path

My scripts rely heavily on external programs and scripts.
I need to be sure that a program I need to call exists.
Manually, I’d check this using [`which`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_(command)) in the command line.

Is there an equivalent to [`File.exist?`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/File.html#method-c-exist-3F) for things in `$PATH`?

(Yes, I guess I could parse the result of `%x[which scriptINeedToRun]`, but that’s not super elegant.)

Comment: I just tested this method, it doesn't work. The command `which` command in the method will return either 1 if the command `command` doesn't exist or 0 if the command `command` exists. So to make the method work, you should replace 127 by 1

Comment: The solution will only work on unix systems where the command `which` is present. This excludes Windows and some other systems. Please remember that Windows is still heavily used among Ruby devs; see my solution for a true cross-platform command.

Comment: Your edit answer is not safe - can be injected with code like ";rm-rf".

Comment: imho the answer from NARKOZ is perfect! `find_executable`

Comment: Solution `ptools` gem worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 133, accepted):

True cross-platform solution, works properly on Windows:

```
# Cross-platform way of finding an executable in the $PATH.
#
#   which('ruby') #=> /usr/bin/ruby
def which(cmd)
  exts = ENV['PATHEXT'] ? ENV['PATHEXT'].split(';') : ['']
  ENV['PATH'].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR).each do |path|
    exts.each do |ext|
      exe = File.join(path, "#{cmd}#{ext}")
      return exe if File.executable?(exe) && !File.directory?(exe)
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

This doesn't use host OS sniffing, and respects $PATHEXT which lists valid file extensions for executables on Windows.

Shelling out to `which` works on many systems but not all.

Comment: Note: The current answer also doesn't handle (reasonable?) edge-cases when an absolute or relative path is included as `cmd` (`/bin/sh` or `..\foo`).

Comment: Why `!File.directory?(exe)` instead of `File.file?(exe)`?

Comment: @mislav for `rspec`  `ENV['PATH']` is `nil`and `exts` are `[]`

Answer (score 87):

Use [`find_executable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/MakeMakefile.html#method-i-find_executable) method from `mkmf` which is included to stdlib.

```
require 'mkmf'

find_executable 'ruby'
#=> "/Users/narkoz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby"

find_executable 'which-ruby'
#=> nil
```

Comment: oh yes indeed - this is the answer

Comment: The only slight catch on Windows is this will default to the the list of executable extensions from the box that built your copy of ruby rather than the local list. `MakeMakefile::CONFIG["EXECUTABLE_EXTS"] = ENV['PATHEXT'].split(';').join(' ')` should fix that.

Comment: Invoking mkmf pollutes your directories with mkmf.log files.

Comment: You can patch the MakeMakefile logger to write the log file to the ruby equivalent of `/dev/null` if you want to avoid creating physical log files. See this gist for an example: https://gist.github.com/mnem/2540fece4ed9d3403b98

Comment: @mnem, this patch didn't work for me. Mac OS, default Ruby 2.0.0, irb.

Comment: @mnem That works for me, but I get stuff dumped to `STDOUT`! How do I turn *that* off?

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there any way to prevent "checking for ls... yes" from STDOUT?

Comment: @Raphael Use the method `find_executable0`. It doesn't print to `STDOUT`

Comment: Requiring `mkmf` is generally a bad idea, and is advised against by ruby developers (see https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12370#note-4) - it is only meant to be used in extconf.rb

Comment: Also `require 'mkmf'` pollutes your global namespace with its functions. It's probably fine in a script but terrible practice in a wider app.

Comment: I found, after someone used this solution at work, that there is a problem where mkmf will clash with ffi-based gems over some method definitions (which I assume both gems define in root namespace). Programs that use both `mkmf` and `ffi` may fail to load.

Answer (score 18):

```
def command?(name)
  `which #{name}`
  $?.success?
end
```

Initially taken from [hub](http://github.com/defunkt/hub), which used `type -t` instead of `which` though (and which failed for both zsh and bash for me).

Comment: which is more widely available on *nix platforms, but doesn't return non-zero exit status on all platforms when nothing is found. `command -v` is the posix-standard and is more reliable on posix platforms.

Comment: Why don't you check for `which #{name}.empty?`?

Comment: Because on SmartOS (and other flavors of Illumnos) 'which command' returns the following string when it does NOT find anything:

`> which foo` returns `no foo in /opt/local/bin /opt/local/sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin`

Answer (score 7):

### Use MakeMakefile#find_executable0 with Logging Disabled

There are a number of good answers already, but here's what I use:

```
require 'mkmf'

def set_mkmf_log(logfile=File::NULL)
  MakeMakefile::Logging.instance_variable_set(:@logfile, logfile)
end

# Return path to cmd as a String, or nil if not found.
def which(cmd)
  old_mkmf_log = MakeMakefile::Logging.instance_variable_get(:@logfile)
  set_mkmf_log(nil)
  path_to_cmd = find_executable0(cmd)
  set_mkmf_log(old_mkmf_log)
  path_to_cmd
end
```

This uses the undocumented **#find_executable0** method invoked by [MakeMakefile#find_executable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/MakeMakefile.html#method-i-find_executable) to return the path without cluttering standard output. The #which method also temporarily redirects the mkmf logfile to */dev/null* to prevent cluttering the current working directory with "mkmf.log" or similar.

Comment: I found, after someone used this solution at work, that there is a problem where `mkmf` will clash with `ffi`-based gems over some method definitions (which I assume both gems define in root namespace). That does limit the usefulness of the solution.

Comment: This isn’t thread-safe and it uses an internal API that’s subject to change.

Answer (score 5):

You can access system environment variables with the ENV hash:

```
puts ENV['PATH']
```

It will return the PATH on your system. So if you want to know if program `nmap` exists, you can do this:

```
ENV['PATH'].split(':').each {|folder| puts File.exists?(folder+'/nmap')}
```

This will print `true` if file was found or `false` otherwise.

Comment: you should probably also check that the file is executable by the user: File.exists?(...) and File.executable?(...). +1 in any case.

Comment: What about expanding path? Maybe it is also better to use File.join or Pathname. Also why not use which? It is a very good tool and it does its job.

Comment: I second @kolrie; this is not cross platform. See my solution

Answer (score 4):

I have this:

```
def command?(name)
  [name,
   *ENV['PATH'].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR).map {|p| File.join(p, name)}
  ].find {|f| File.executable?(f)}
end
```

works for full paths as well as commands:

```
irb(main):043:0> command?("/bin/bash")
=> "/bin/bash"
irb(main):044:0> command?("bash")
=> "/bin/bash"
irb(main):006:0> command?("bush")
=> nil
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I'm using. This is platform neutral (`File::PATH_SEPARATOR` is `":"` on Unix and `";"` on Windows), only looks for program files that actually are executable by the effective user of the current process, and terminates as soon as the program is found:

```
##
# Returns +true+ if the +program+ executable is found in the user's path.
def has_program?(program)
  ENV['PATH'].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR).any? do |directory|
    File.executable?(File.join(directory, program.to_s))
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't respect the $PATHEXT environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add that `which` takes the flag `-s` for silent mode, which only sets the success flag, removing the need for redirecting the output.

Comment: On my system `which` does not accept an -s flag, is that specified somewhere?

Comment: `man which` told me about my system. But, my man page says "Some shells may provide a builtin which command which is similar or identical to this utility.  Consult the builtin(1) manual page." YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

This is an improved version based on [@mislav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5471032/445221). This would allow any type of path input and strictly follows how `cmd.exe` chooses the file to execute in Windows.

```
# which(cmd) :: string or nil
#
# Multi-platform implementation of "which".
# It may be used with UNIX-based and DOS-based platforms.
#
# The argument can not only be a simple command name but also a command path
# may it be relative or complete.
#
def which(cmd)
  raise ArgumentError.new("Argument not a string: #{cmd.inspect}") unless cmd.is_a?(String)
  return nil if cmd.empty?
  case RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']
  when /cygwin/
    exts = nil
  when /dos|mswin|^win|mingw|msys/
    pathext = ENV['PATHEXT']
    exts = pathext ? pathext.split(';').select{ |e| e[0] == '.' } : ['.com', '.exe', '.bat']
  else
    exts = nil
  end
  if cmd[File::SEPARATOR] or (File::ALT_SEPARATOR and cmd[File::ALT_SEPARATOR])
    if exts
      ext = File.extname(cmd)
      if not ext.empty? and exts.any?{ |e| e.casecmp(ext).zero? } \
      and File.file?(cmd) and File.executable?(cmd)
        return File.absolute_path(cmd)
      end
      exts.each do |ext|
        exe = "#{cmd}#{ext}"
        return File.absolute_path(exe) if File.file?(exe) and File.executable?(exe)
      end
    else
      return File.absolute_path(cmd) if File.file?(cmd) and File.executable?(cmd)
    end
  else
    paths = ENV['PATH']
    paths = paths ? paths.split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR).select{ |e| File.directory?(e) } : []
    if exts
      ext = File.extname(cmd)
      has_valid_ext = (not ext.empty? and exts.any?{ |e| e.casecmp(ext).zero? })
      paths.unshift('.').each do |path|
        if has_valid_ext
          exe = File.join(path, "#{cmd}")
          return File.absolute_path(exe) if File.file?(exe) and File.executable?(exe)
        end
        exts.each do |ext|
          exe = File.join(path, "#{cmd}#{ext}")
          return File.absolute_path(exe) if File.file?(exe) and File.executable?(exe)
        end
      end
    else
      paths.each do |path|
        exe = File.join(path, cmd)
        return File.absolute_path(exe) if File.file?(exe) and File.executable?(exe)
      end
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

Comment: @Barry It's not you who decide what is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Solution based on rogeriovl, but complete function with execution test rather than existence test.

```
def command_exists?(command)
  ENV['PATH'].split(':').each {|folder| File.executable?(File.join(folder, command))}
end
```

Will work only for UNIX (Windows does not use colon as a separator)

Comment: Ok thanks. But please note this will only work for UNIX. Fine with removing the rant, but the note should stay there.

Answer (score 1):

On linux I use:

```
exists = `which #{command}`.size.>(0)
```

Unfortunately, `which` is not a POSIX command and so behaves differently on Mac, BSD, etc (i.e., throws an error if the command is not found).  Maybe the ideal solution would be to use

```
`command -v #{command}`.size.>(0)  # fails!: ruby can't access built-in functions
```

But this fails because ruby seems to not be capable of accessing built-in functions.  But `command -v` would be the POSIX way to do this.

Comment: This is right. You just need to ``sh -c 'command -v #command'``, and you've got it. I tried editing your answer here to that effect, but it was rejected because apparently, I was "altering your meaning".

Comment: On linux I use:
    exists = `which #{command}`.size.>(0)

Unfortunately, `which` is not a POSIX command and so behaves differently on Mac, BSD, etc (i.e., throws an error if the command is not found).

The ideal solution is to use 

    `sh -c 'command -v #{command}'`.size.>(0)

The `sh -c` is necessary because otherwise ruby will not be capable of accessing built-in functions.  
But `command -v` would be the POSIX way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tweak of rogeriopvl's answer, making it cross platform:

```
require 'rbconfig'

def is_windows?
  Config::CONFIG["host_os"] =~ /mswin|mingw/
end

def exists_in_path?(file)
  entries = ENV['PATH'].split(is_windows? ? ";" : ":")
  entries.any? {|f| File.exists?("#{f}/#{file}")}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

for jruby, any of the solutions that depend on `mkmf` may not work, as it has a C extension.

for jruby, the following is an easy way to check if something is executable on the path:

```
main » unix_process = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git status")
=> #<Java::JavaLang::UNIXProcess:0x64fa1a79>
main » unix_process.exitValue()
=> 0
main »
```

if the executable isn't there, it will raise a runtime error, so you may want to do this in a try/catch block in your actual usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
#####################################################
# add methods to see if there's an executable that's executable
#####################################################
class File
  class << self
    ###########################################
    # exists and executable
    ###########################################
    def cmd_executable?(cmd)
      !ENV['PATH'].split(':').select { |f| executable?(join(f, cmd[/^[^ \n\r]*/])) }.empty?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the solution that question-asker [Yannick Wurm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183988/yannick-wurm) used at first, [in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2108727/3):

```rb
def command?(command)
  system("which #{command} > /dev/null 2>&1")
end
```

Comment: [In 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2108727/4), the author of this answer wrote “Update: a few new answers have come in – at least some of these offer better solutions.”

Answer (score 0):

The [`ptools`](https://github.com/djberg96/ptools) gem adds a method `File.which` to the [`File`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html) class:

```rb
require "ptools"

File.which("ruby") #=> '/usr/local/bin/ruby'
```

That method’s implementation as of ptools 1.5.0: [`self.which` in `lib/ptools.rb`](https://github.com/djberg96/ptools/blob/ptools-1.5.0/lib/ptools.rb#L93). That implementation is under the [Apache License 2.0](https://github.com/djberg96/ptools/blob/ptools-1.5.0/LICENSE).

Answer (score -10):

Not so much elegant but it works :).

```
def cmdExists?(c)
  system(c + " > /dev/null")
  return false if $?.exitstatus == 127
  true
end
```

**Warning**: This is *NOT* recommended, *dangerous* advice!

Comment: Could be long, better use system("which " + c) then.

Comment: call `cmdExists?('rm -rf ~')`. Also ruby convention is to name methods like `cmd_exists?`

Comment: Really *excellent* advice. This can even wipe your hdd. NOT RECOMMENDED!