# Platform-independent way of detecting if git is installed

Tags: ruby, windows, git, shell, detect

This is how I detect git in ruby:

```
`which git 2>/dev/null` and $?.success?
```

However, this is not cross-platform. It fails on non-unix systems or those without the `which` command (although I'm not sure what those are).

I need a way to detect git that satisfies these conditions:

1. works reliably cross-platform, even on Windows
2. doesn't output anything to $stdout or $stderr
3. small amount of code

---

**Update:** the solution is to avoid using `which` altogether and to redirect output to `NUL` on Windows.

```
require 'rbconfig'
void = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /msdos|mswin|djgpp|mingw/ ? 'NUL' : '/dev/null'
system "git --version >>#{void} 2>&1"
```

The `system` command returns true on success and false on failure, saving us the trip to `$?.success?` which is needed when using backticks.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108727/which-in-ruby-checking-if-program-exists-in-path-from-ruby/2108757#2108757 could help?

Comment: Forgive my potential foolishness, but doesn't `which` write to stdout?

Comment: @Steven: of course it does, but in its own subshell, and you can see that I used backticks which captures that output in a return value which I then discard. If `which` wrote something to STDERR, ruby would forward that to $stderr of the main program (something I don't wish to happen) so I used `2>/dev/null` to handle that.

Comment: @mislav: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the techniques you're using, but if you can intercept both stdout and stderr, you can avoid relying on `which` and just run `git --version` instead. I suspect that I'm miles off...

Comment: One point about RUBY_PLATFORM is that will not detect Java properly. See this post: http://blog.emptyway.com/2009/11/03/proper-way-to-detect-windows-platform-in-ruby/

Comment: Thanks Luis, didn't know that! Now corrected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not such thing as `/dev/null` on Windows.

One approach we have been taking in different projects is define `NULL` based on `RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']`

```
NULL = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /mingw|mswin/ ? 'NUL' : '/dev/null'
```

Then use that to redirect both STDOUT and STDERR to it.

As for which, I made a trivial reference on [my blog](http://blog.mmediasys.com/2008/10/21/guas-is-giving-unwanted-advice-series-1/)

But, if you just want to check git presence and not location, no need to do which, with a simple system call and check of the resulting in `$?` will be enough.

Hope this helps

Comment: When I call `git` and then check `$?.success?`, the result is always true, even if git is not installed. (ruby 1.9.2, i686-pc-mingw32 on Win XP)

Comment: BTW, had used this technique with rake-compiler to detect gmake/make across platforms: https://github.com/luislavena/rake-compiler/blob/master/lib/rake/extensiontask.rb#L352-354

Comment: I can see that it works now. I must have done something wrong the first time around

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution which avoids shelling out to detect executables and is also able to reliably detect where the executable is located. It's an alternative to `which`.

```
def which cmd
  exts = ENV['PATHEXT'] ? ENV['PATHEXT'].split(';') : ['']
  ENV['PATH'].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR).each do |path|
    exts.each { |ext|
      exe = "#{path}/#{cmd}#{ext}"
      return exe if File.executable? exe
    }
  end
  return nil
end
```

Usage:

```
# Mac OS X
where 'ruby'
#=> /opt/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/bin/ruby

# Windows
where 'ruby'
#=> C:\Program Files\Ruby192\bin/ruby.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps running on [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) and using [JGit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/) could be an option to really go platform-independent.

Comment: but 'which' won't run on windows. The prob. is not ruby portability.

Comment: @zengr: The idea would be not to use the native git implementation at all, but JGit, a pure Java implementation of git.

Comment: but what if the end user is using git (and not jgit), it will go undetected and OPs app will install jgit WITH git which was already on the machine.

Comment: @zengr I don't know about the actual use case here, but if the app needs to make use of git it could bundle JGit, use that, and not install anything.

Comment: limiting myself to just one Ruby implementation isn't something I had in mind when I asked for "platform-independent" :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you will need to do this:

1. Check if machine is windows and unix based
2. If Unix, use `which`
3. If Windows, [Is there an equivalent of 'which' on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-windows)