# Failover provisioners in Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, ansible

Is it possible to run one Vagrant provisioner based on the success or failure of a previous provisioner?

I have a Vagrant VM provisioned with Ansible that I'd like to distribute to others. The problem is, some of those people are running Windows and Ansible doesn't support Windows. I can work around that, but I'd like to catch the failing provisioner and do something else instead.

To be precise, I want to run a shell provisioner only if the Ansible provisioner fails. The Vagrantfile is just Ruby, so it seems like this should be possible, one way or another.

```rb
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  # This fails on Windows
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "vagrant/ansible/main.yml"
  end

  # Run this provisioner IF AND ONLY IF the Ansible provisioner has failed:
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "failover.sh"
```

Vagrant returns this error when trying to run the Ansible provisioner on Windows:

```
[default] Running provisioner: ansible...
The executable 'ansible-playbook' Vagrant is trying to run was not found
in the %PATH% variable. This is an error. Please verify this software is
installed and on the path.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to have a fail over provisioner... Vagrant seems to just stop on error without having a way to continue.

As you say the `Vagrantfile` is just Ruby so a better option might be to detect whether ansible is installed on the machine first before attempting to run the provisioner.

Using the which function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108727/which-in-ruby-checking-if-program-exists-in-path-from-ruby/5471032#5471032) combined with the following should allow you to do what you want to do:

```
if which('ansible-playbook')
    # This fails on Windows
    config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = "vagrant/ansible/main.yml"
    end
else
    # Run this provisioner IF AND ONLY IF the Ansible provisioner has failed:
    config.vm.provision "shell", path: "failover.sh"
end
```

Comment: good point, though in this case it might be easier to just try running ansible-playbook into variable, something like this: `do_ansible = \`ansible-playbook --version\` rescue nil` ?

Comment: Yeah that is a bit more simple!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for a single command, check the platform:

```
if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows?
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "failover.sh"
else
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
  ansible.playbook = "vagrant/ansible/main.yml"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows hosts run the ansible-playbook inside the guest operating system.

failover.sh

```
sudo apt-get install ansible -y
ansible-playbook ansible/playbooks/vagrant-playbook.yml -i ansible/conf/hosts_local -c local
```

(mount your ansible directory into the vagrantbox and provide an )

host_local

```
[default]
127.0.0.1
```